# Getting a response from the browser (HTTPS, C#)

Tags: c#, browser, https, response, fiddlercore

It is necessary to receive data from the browser, I mean the authorization code. I use the `OAuth2` from `Yahoo` service. This code is displayed in the address bar of the browser after successful authorization, than redirect to `redirect_uri=...`. `Process` is used to start the browser, after that I try to listen on port `XXXX` with `HttpListener`, however even if I get some response, it is a meaningless set of characters . (`UTF-8`, etc. tried, the result is the same)

How can I get the authorization code from the browser after successful authorization?

## Code with `HttpListener`

```
static void SniffPort()
{
    byte[] input = new byte[] { 1 };
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 5000));
    socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, input, null);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int len = socket.Receive(buffer);
            if (len <= 40) continue;
            string bin = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, len);
            Console.WriteLine(bin);
        }
    });
}

static HttpListener _httpListener = new HttpListener();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
    _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("https://localhost:5000/");
    _httpListener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
    SniffPort();

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\chrome-win\chrome.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    Process p = new Process();
    startInfo.Arguments = "--app=https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5000/&response_type=code&language=en-us";
    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Also I had idea with the `FiddlerCore`, but after using it, you have to change the settings related to the proxy in `inetcpl.cpl`. It also doesn't work if the browser remembers the user and logs in immediately after starting the browser, `FiddlerCore` does not provide this information.

## Code with `FiddlerCore`

```
public class HttpProxy : IDisposable
{
    public HttpProxy()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(5000, true, false);
    }

    void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("REQ: {0}", oSession.url));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }
}

static HttpListener _httpListener = new HttpListener();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpProxy httpProxy = new HttpProxy();
    
    //Launching the browser as in the code above.
}
```

Comment: Data may be GZIP or Base 64 string (or both).

Comment: @jdweng, should I decode it as `GZIP` or `Base64`? Maybe I need to know private browser key for decryption?

Comment: It is probably not encryption.  GZIP : see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0   Base 64 : string input = Convert.FromBase64String(string);